# Work with addresses in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, emu8086

So I can't figure out why my program doesn't work and the different outputs for different input. I have 2 variables:

```
   static_num1_ptr    dw 7 ;
   static_num1_ptr_ptr dw [static_num1_ptr];
```

I have this code:

```
    mov     bx,static_num1_ptr_ptr;
    mov     bx,[bx];
    mov     ax,[bx];
    call    print_num
```

I need to change the declaration of the num1-ptr and num1_ptr_ptr in order to print 7. I can't change the 4 lines of code. I tried changing num1_ptr_ptr to be equal to [num1_ptr] and num1_ptr to be 7. But that gives me 0. 
Can someone help me understand the logic here?
I use emu8086

Comment: Please show us the code with these changes made. What assembler syntax  is this?

Comment: tags are edited. 8086

Comment: Do you mean emu8086?  Different assemblers with different syntax can build code for 8086, e.g. NASM where `mov     bx,static_num1_ptr_ptr;` is a `mov bx, imm16`, or TASM where it's a load.

Comment: I understand. Yes I mean emu8086

Comment: I don't think your code assembles like this, which might cause the binary from the previous run to be executed instead, causing the weird behaviour you observe.

Comment: I'm really new to assembly. What do you mean by that? What can I change? This program is given, I just need to change the 2 declaration lines in order to print 7.

Comment: are you aware emu8086 has built-in debugger, so you can see yourself how the code did assemble, what is content of registers and memory, and how does it change after each instruction.  It's not clear how `dw [static_num1_ptr]` will assemble, probably as `dw offset static_num1_ptr`? It doesn't make sense from x86 ASM point of view, so it's the quirky/relaxed emu8086 syntax (MASM like), which makes it compile, but it's not readable for humans, what was the intent of programmer. Looks like there's maybe one too many dereferences (removing `mov bx,[bx]` helps?). Will be obvious in debugger.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't change the 4 lines of code.

I think the solution lies in closely reading the names of these labels!

If the first label reads *static_num1_**ptr***, it most probably means that it is supposed to be a pointer to *num1* and not the value of *num1* itself.
You'll need a third line here:

```
static_num1         dw 7
static_num1_ptr     dw offset static_num1
static_num1_ptr_ptr dw offset static_num1_ptr
```

Now your 4 lines of code

```
mov  bx, static_num1_ptr_ptr
mov  bx, [bx]
mov  ax, [bx]
call print_num
```

will correctly dereference twice (`[bx]`) and print the value 7.